# Phonegap: Android/iOS is not showing live stream video using jwplayer

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jwplayer

Want to develop live stream tv app for android and ios using phonegap. For this purpose i am using license jwplayer for streaming video. Here i am using RTMP url and player is working well in browser. But show error in android and ios.

Comment: You can't use RTMP on mobile, you need to use HLS.

Comment: @Linkon Islam how did you solve this?Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718171/how-to-use-trendnet-ip-camera-live-streaming-url-in-phonegap-app

Answer (score 2):

RTMP is a Flash protocol. There is no Flash on any mobile device. You need to use HLS for streaming to a  mobile device.